# SmartGWT Grid not working when updgrading SmartGWT 6

Tags: smartgwt

We work with build 2016-05-07, and updgrading to 2016-12-25 (for Firefox issues with SmartGwt) makes Grid with JSON RestDataSource no working. Other Grids with other DataSources work without problems.

We get this error:

> 0:41:18.630:XRP1:WARN:RPCManager:The server failed to return a formatted response at all. - response: {status: -16,
>   data: "The server failed to return a formatted ..."[56],
>   httpResponseCode: 200,
>   httpResponseText: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{"response":{"endRow"..."[968],
>   transactionNum: 2,
>   clientContext: Obj,
>   internalClientContext: Obj,
>   httpHeaders: Obj,
>   context: Obj,
>   queueStatus: -1,
>   startRow: 0,
>   endRow: 0,
>   totalRows: 0}

Javascript Heap Error

```
isc.B.push.isc.A.addToMasterLog @   ISC_Core.js:1134
isc_c_Log_addLogMessage @   ISC_Core.js:1133
isc_c_Log_log   @   ISC_Core.js:1126
logMessage  @   ISC_Core.js:1115
isc.RPCManager.logMessage   @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1788
logWarn @   ISC_Core.js:1115
isc_c_RPCManager_runDefaultErrorHandling    @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1725
isc_c_RPCManager_handleError    @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1711
isc_c_RPCManager__handleError   @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1710
isc.B.push.isc.A.fetchRemoteDataReply   @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1897
isc_c_Class_fireCallback    @   ISC_Core.js:284
isc_Class_fireCallback  @   ISC_Core.js:352
isc_DataSource_fireResponseCallbacks    @   ISC_DataBinding.js:740
isc_DataSource__completeResponseProcessing  @   ISC_DataBinding.js:738
isc_DataSource__handleJSONReply @   ISC_DataBinding.js:622
isc.B.push.isc.A.$379   @   ISC_DataBinding.js:625
isc_c_Class_fireCallback    @   ISC_Core.js:284
isc_Class_fireCallback  @   ISC_Core.js:352
isc_c_RPCManager_fireReplyCallback  @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1701
$wnd.isc.RPCManager.fireReplyCallback   @   SmartGwtEntryPoint.java:418
isc_c_RPCManager_fireReplyCallbacks @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1706
isc_c_RPCManager_performOperationReply  @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1699
isc_c_RPCManager__performTransactionReply   @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1684
isc_c_RPCManager_performTransactionReply    @   ISC_DataBinding.js:1607
(anonymous) @   VM1807:3
isc_c_Class_fireCallback    @   ISC_Core.js:284
isc_c_Comm_performXmlTransactionReply   @   ISC_Core.js:1385
(anonymous) @   VM1806:3
isc_c_Class_fireCallback    @   ISC_Core.js:284
isc_c_Comm__fireXMLCallback @   ISC_Core.js:1365
_15 @   ISC_Core.js:1373
```